# I need a minimal working example of a XUL tree with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, xul

I am trying to use [tree#Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tree#Examples) and [Tree_Widget_Changes#Checkbox_columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tree_Widget_Changes#Checkbox_columns) (from MDN) to create a preference box where users can (de)select grouped options. For this I want to have main categories *without* a checkbox, under which sit a collapsable list of child items *with* checkboxes... the tree example at the first link works, but I can't get it to display checboxes, and I can't find any documentation on how to have the "root" items have no checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the following css for the "checked" checkboxes to appear as checked:

```
/* default style for checkbox column */
treechildren::-moz-tree-checkbox(checked) { list-style-image: url("chrome://global/skin/checkbox/cbox-check.gif"); }
```

For the "root" rows problem, as far as I know, a `treeitem` groups multiple `treerow`s. Try setting the `label` attribute of `treeitem` element and place any child `treerow` inside it.